# Swap subarrays of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pygtk, pycairo

First a bit of context.

I am trying to draw into a Gdk (actually pygtk) pixbuf with Cairo
(actually pycairo).  My original code looked like this:

```
import cairo as C
import gtk.gdk as GG

FMT = C.FORMAT_ARGB32
CSP = GG.COLORSPACE_RGB

st = C.ImageSurface.format_stride_for_width(FMT, zw)
surf = C.ImageSurface(FMT, zw, zh)
c = C.Context(surf)

# draw into c here ...

pixels = surf.get_data()
return GG.pixbuf_new_from_data(pixels, CSP, True, 8, zw, zh, st)
```

For a time, it looked like this would just work, until I tried to draw
colors instead of just black text.  It turns out the two libraries disagree on
byte order, like so:

```
# !!! FIXME !!! cairo ARGB surfaces and gdk pixbufs disagree on bytesex:
# cairo: LSB --> B G R A <-- MSB
# gdk:   LSB --> R G B A <-- MSB
# !!! WTF !!!
```

The result is (after blitting from the pixbuf to screen) an image with
red and blue channels swapped :-(

So, if I keep using pixbufs (as I want to) I need to postprocess the data,
swapping every 1st byte with every 3rd.  I can do that in plain python:

```
def changesex(data):
    i0 = 0
    i2 = 2
    l = len(data)
    while i2 < l:
        temp = data[i0]
        data[i0] = data[i2]
        data[i2] = temp
        i0 += 4
        i2 += 4
```

but I thought using numpy might be faster if there is a built-in
operator for this written in C.  Something like this:

```
a = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)
a.shape = (len(data) / 4, 4)
temp = a[:,0]
a[:,0] = a[:,2]
a[:,2] = temp
```

Am I just dreaming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Noting `a` your initial `(N,4)` array of `B,G,R,A`, you could get a `(N,4)` representation as `R,G,B,A` rather simply using some advanced indexing:

```
a = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)
a.shape = (-1, 4)
rearranged = a[:,[2,1,0,3]]
```

Comment: Yup, I found this myself by a combination of trial-error and going through similar questions here.  Thanks though!

Comment: for me rearranged = a[:,:,[2,1,0,3]] worked without the additional shape command

Comment: Also, `rearranged = a[...,[2,1,0,3]]` should work for any number of axes (for, say, batch learning or something silly like that).